# Ionic: Form Validation for dynamically created items

Tags: angular, validation, typescript, ionic-framework

I have tried every method of form validation for dynamically created items using `ngFor` but "required" validation doesn't seem to work.

The closest I could get is [this](http://brianflove.com/2016/10/16/dynamic-form-group-custom-validation-angular2/) tutorial. But didn't work.

What is the best way to validate many elements conditionally (even for `Validate.required`)?

Comment: I am also facing same problem.